# Code with Three 20 latest version facebook-three20-726841e rejected by Apple

Tags: iphone

I got this response from Apple when i submitted my App with Three 20.I did my project in Xcode 4 and used the latest version of Three 20 i.e. facebook-three20-726841e.
I already did the changes in other posts.
It got rejected again.

Our system has determined your app is using private or undocumented APIs:
The app references private or undocumented symbols

```
OBJC_IVAR_$_UITouch._locationInWindow
OBJC_IVAR_$_UITouch._phase
OBJC_IVAR_$_UITouch._previousLocationInWindow
OBJC_IVAR_$_UITouch._tapCount
OBJC_IVAR_$_UITouch._timestamp
OBJC_IVAR_$_UITouch._touchFlags
OBJC_IVAR_$_UITouch._view
OBJC_IVAR_$_UITouch._window
```

Please help me with this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The non-public API that is included in your application is UITouch._touchFlags.

See if this helps http://cocoatouchdown.blogspot.com/2009/12/uitouchtouchflags-are-private.html

Also something useful about this http://groups.google.com/group/three20/browse_thread/thread/c442af6e39a918b0?fwc=1

Comment: Thanks for that. I have gone through this and made the changes but my code got rejected again! Is there any other way than this?

Comment: Try posting a line to the creator about it maybe so if the problem is already solved you can include that version of Three20 in your application

Comment: Finally  my app got accepted after 3 rejections!!
Juz removed  DEBUG in all xcode project files of three20 included in the app.

Comment: thanks for the update! good that u posted the solution so it can help others. Cheers!

Comment: Hey @Senorina, I am too facing the same problem. I have removed every occurrence of DEBUG in all of the three20 projects used inside my project. But still this dumb appstore submission process keeps giving me the same error! Do you guys know of any other reason why this is happening? Thanks!